fundamental differences between in-place merging and in-place mergesort
I have been pondering the basic big O performance of the functions,
in isolation or in collaboration with each other.
So IPM(S) is a function that does an in-place merge of S,
and IPMS(S) is a function that does an in-place merge sort.
So IPM( [1, 3, 5, 7, 2, 4, 6, 8 ] ) = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 ] ,
and IPMS( [ 7, 5, 3, 1, 8, 6, 4, 2 ] ) = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 ] .
My questions are :

what in the current "state of the art" are the best implementations
(n big O terms) for IPM and IPMS

do the best implementations of IPMS use the best implementations
of IPM, or are there best case IPMS that do not follow the structure of
the classic merge sort


I have been experimenting with an IPM that might at worse case
(for S of length N) require ~ 4N/3 comparisons and 8N/3 value copies.
However I do not know how good that is wrt #1
(ie if inferior to the current state of the art, end work on it now) ,
and even if it is good, whether it would be of consequence to the best IPMS.
It seems that O(N log N) is a common worst case bound for IPM.

Wiki has an article on block merge sort:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_sort
There has been research and development, as recently as March 2023 for optimized implementations of block merge sort, some are over 1000 lines of code.
https://github.com/HolyGrailSortProject
Since most systems have a lot of memory these days, there isn't much need for an in place merge sort, so this is mostly an academic exercise. It would be rare to sort that many integers, and if sorting records, what is usually sorted is an array of pointers or indexes to the records, after which the records can be sorted according to the array of pointers or indexes in O(n) time:
Sort an array in place according to a sort order defined in another array
